# How to resizing CSS radio button and keep text in middle

Tags: css

I'm not sure which part to change on this radio button to make it smaller and keep the text in line with the inner button.  The changes I made puts the text to the top of the radio button.  Could you advise which bits are necessary to change to keep everything in line.

This is a big radio button

```css
.button {
  background: #cfe7fa;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #cfe7fa), color-stop(100%, #6393c1));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  border: 1px solid #6393c1;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 15px Arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  line-height: 41px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.button:hover .inner {
  opacity: .5;
}
.button input {
  display: none;
}
.button input:checked + .outer .inner {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button .outer {
  background: #2989d8;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #2989d8), color-stop(99%, #101354));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}
.button .inner {
  background: #e4f5fc;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #e4f5fc), color-stop(50%, #bfe8f9), color-stop(51%, #9fd8ef), color-stop(100%, #2ab0ed));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  width: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <label class="button">
    <input type="radio" name="button" />
    <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
    Add Details
  </label>
  <label class="button">
    <input type="radio" name="button" />
    <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
    Choice 2
  </label>

</div>
```

I've attempted to change what I thought but the writing is now at the top of the button and I'd like it in the centre, so I must be changing the wrong parts

HTML after changes

```css
.button {
  background: #cfe7fa;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #cfe7fa), color-stop(100%, #6393c1));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  border: 1px solid #6393c1;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font: 10px Arial, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  line-height: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.button:hover .inner {
  opacity: .5;
}
.button input {
  display: none;
}
.button input:checked + .outer .inner {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button .outer {
  background: #2989d8;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #2989d8), color-stop(99%, #101354));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #2989d8 0%, #101354 99%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 10px;
}
.button .inner {
  background: #e4f5fc;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #e4f5fc), color-stop(50%, #bfe8f9), color-stop(51%, #9fd8ef), color-stop(100%, #2ab0ed));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #e4f5fc 0%, #bfe8f9 50%, #9fd8ef 51%, #2ab0ed 100%);
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  margin: .5px;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <label class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="button" />
        <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
        Add Details
      </label>
      <label class="button">
        <input type="radio" name="button" />
        <span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
        Choice 2
      </label>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `line-height: 3px;` to `line-height:22.5px;`

See also the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8v237xe/1/) example.

Comment: Yes, thought about the same, but then i checked it in Chrome... (not so perfectly aligned)...few more tweaks are needed, probably....

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and your suggestion. I will change it :)

Comment: That worked a treat, if I resize again (maybe for a different page or something), how did you work out line-height 22.5px when the original size of the big button was 41px?

Comment: maybe you can try this, it is not the solution but it seems to be that can help you http://jsfiddle.net/94p8eqp6/